# Probability of passengers exiting an elevator

Tags: probability, self-study

I'm not sure if I'm doing this problem correctly. The question is to `find the probability that 4 passengers exit an elevator at different floors, where there are 10 floors and it is equally likely that a passenger exits the elevator`. Here's what I've done:

```
A = 4 passengers at different floors
B = 4 passengers at same floor

P(A) = 1 - P(B)
P(B) = 10 / 10,000
P(A) = 0.999
```

Basically I'm confused on the sample size. Is 10,000 correct by multiplying the amount of floors each passenger can exit together (`10 * 10 * 10 * 10`)? If I could get some verification, it would greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Edit:

The 4 passengers are already in the elevator at the start of the problem, and they can each exit once at floor 1, 2, 3, ... , 9, 10. I'm interested in the probability that each passenger exits on a different floor. That is, if passenger 1 exits on floor 2, the rest of the three passengers cannot exit on floor 2. Also, each passenger has to exit on a floor.

Comment: So 4 passengers enter an elevator and you are interested in the probability, that each passenger leaves at a different floor? And they cannot exit on the floor that they entered from? Did they all enter from the same floor?

Comment: In your equation, $1 - P(B)$ is the probability that all passengers don't exit on the same floor, which is different from the probability that each exits at a different floor. Suggest you first edit your Question to clarify the exact rules as requested by @user2974951.  Then try a different solution, perhaps starting by choosing the 4 floors at which passengers exit.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should've been more clear. I know there are 10 possibilities that the 4 passengers exit on the same floor, but how do you calculate the overall sample size is what trips me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackExchange @JerryP.

The 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 gives all the different possible exit-combinations for the 4 passanger. Passanger_1 can exit on 10 different floors. Passanger_2 as well. So lets say Passanger_1 exits at the first floor, Passanger_2 could exit on floor 1 to 10. If Passanger_1 exits at the second flor, Passanger_2 could again exit on floor 1 to 10. Since Passanger_1 can exit on 1 to 10 and Passanger_2 as well the combination is 10*10.

I've made a little simulation using r to show this a bit more visible (at least i hope)

```
test = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 4))
names(test) = c(paste0("passanger_", rep(1:4)))

test = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 4))
names(test) = c(paste0("passanger_", rep(1:4)))


rowcounter = 0
for(p1 in 1:10)
{
  for(p2 in 1:10)
  {
    for(p3 in 1:10)
    {
      for(p4 in 1:10)
      {
        test = rbind(test, data.frame("passanger_1" = p1, "passanger_2" = p2, "passanger_3" = p3, "passanger_4" = p4))
        rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
        print(rowcounter)
      }
    }
  }
}
rowcounter
# > rowcounter
# [1] 10000

head(test, 25)
# > head(test, 25)
# passanger_1 passanger_2 passanger_3 passanger_4
# 1            1           1           1           1
# 2            1           1           1           2
# 3            1           1           1           3
# 4            1           1           1           4
# 5            1           1           1           5
# 6            1           1           1           6
# 7            1           1           1           7
# 8            1           1           1           8
# 9            1           1           1           9
# 10           1           1           1          10
# 11           1           1           2           1
# 12           1           1           2           2
# 13           1           1           2           3
# 14           1           1           2           4
# 15           1           1           2           5
# 16           1           1           2           6
# 17           1           1           2           7
# 18           1           1           2           8
# 19           1           1           2           9
# 20           1           1           2          10
# 21           1           1           3           1
# 22           1           1           3           2
# 23           1           1           3           3
# 24           1           1           3           4
# 25           1           1           3           5

tail(test, 25)
# > tail(test, 25)
# passanger_1 passanger_2 passanger_3 passanger_4
# 9976           10          10           8           6
# 9977           10          10           8           7
# 9978           10          10           8           8
# 9979           10          10           8           9
# 9980           10          10           8          10
# 9981           10          10           9           1
# 9982           10          10           9           2
# 9983           10          10           9           3
# 9984           10          10           9           4
# 9985           10          10           9           5
# 9986           10          10           9           6
# 9987           10          10           9           7
# 9988           10          10           9           8
# 9989           10          10           9           9
# 9990           10          10           9          10
# 9991           10          10          10           1
# 9992           10          10          10           2
# 9993           10          10          10           3
# 9994           10          10          10           4
# 9995           10          10          10           5
# 9996           10          10          10           6
# 9997           10          10          10           7
# 9998           10          10          10           8
# 9999           10          10          10           9
# 10000          10          10          10          10

possible = NROW(test) # how many different exit-combinations are there
possible
# > possible
# [1] 10000

wanted = sum(apply(test, 1, function(f) length(unique(f))) == 4) # how many are there where all 4 exit-floors are different? 
wanted
# > wanted
# [1] 5040

wanted/possible
# > wanted/possible
# [1] 0.504


# check if this is true

10/10 * 9/10 * 8/10 * 7/10
# > 10/10 * 9/10 * 8/10 * 7/10
# [1] 0.504
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. I totally blanked out on the `P(B)` until I saw your code and explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped :)